# Home express route not rendering

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Currently building out a page using Node.just, Express.is and EJS.  Attempting to create a home route which can display a personalized message, and a compliments route.  They will both display random compliments and colors when refreshed.  My compliments route is working, however my home route isn’t.  Wasn’t sure if I’m able to use my compliments.ejs for both routes so I did create an index.ejs with the same code and tried that, also didn’t work.  Not sure what I’m doing wrong.  I’ve included screen shots of both my code and the local host pages.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Change `app.get('/:', ...);` to `app.get('/', ...);`. Maybe that's it.

Comment: Agree with @pzaenger. The `It's almost beer o' clock` killed me btw

Comment: I will try that thx guys!